# Оптимизация больших изображений для сайта

Tags: html, css, css3, оптимизация, оптимизация-сайтов

На сайте используется ряд изображений с высоким разрешением от `2500px`.

[pageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) конечно же ругается, поэтому пытаюсь использовать современный атрибут `srcset` для изображений:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <img srcset="https://dummyimage.com/2560x400/333/fff 2x,
               https://dummyimage.com/1280x400/333/fff 1x"
       sizes="(min-width: 1280px) 1280px, 100vw"
       alt="A title">
</article>
```

Для высоко разрешения так и использую в `2500px`, а для обычного делаю эти же картинки в уменьшенным в 2 раза разрешением.

Пример записи `img` для реального проекта:

```
<img src="images/img-1-1x.jpg" srcset="images/2x/img-1-2x.jpg 2x" alt="" class="img-fluid">
```

**В итоге** по всем "возможностям" pagespeed ругается на эти изображения и ругается на `img-1-2x.jpg` Т.е. на телефонах вместо того чтобы отображать  `img-1-1x.jpg` отображается большая картинка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И такие проблемы только для моб. девайсов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Для десктопа** все отлично, скорость **90+**!

По совету использую [Echo.js lazy load](https://toddmotto.com/echo-js-simple-javascript-image-lazy-loading/), но этот lazy load на телефонах (особенно при плохом интернете) не все фото грузит.

---

**Update:**

Как оказалось запись:

```
<img srcset="https://dummyimage.com/2560x400/333/fff 2x,
           https://dummyimage.com/1280x400/333/fff 1x"
   sizes="(min-width: 1280px) 1280px, 100vw"
   alt="A title">
```

**не валидна**!

При использовании атрибута `sizes` запись должна быть подобна этой:

```
 <img srcset="https://dummyimage.com/2560x400/333/fff 1280w,
           https://dummyimage.com/1280x400/333/fff 640w"
   sizes="(min-width: 1280px) 1280px, 100vw"
   alt="A title">
```

Просмотрев [видеоурок](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gHLPBlzGRT8) с рекомендацией о сжатии изображения в [squoosh.app](https://squoosh.app/), сделала изображения с разрешением `.webp`. Подключила с использованием `picture`:

```
   <picture>
     <source srcset="images/Image-1x.webp 1x,
                     images/2x/Image-2x.webp 2x"
             type="image/webp">

     <img src="images/Image-1x.jpg" 
          srcset="images/2x/Image-2x.jpg 2x" 
          alt="" >
   </picture>
```

Изображения в формате `.webp` весят около `200-300 кб`, это при том что в большом разрешении около 2 Мб.

В итоге **скорость на страницах упала до 10 - 13**, и изображения отображаются только в хроме. Стоит последняя версия firefox, но почему-то и в нем не отображаются картинки.

[caniuse.com/#feat=picture](https://caniuse.com/#feat=picture)

**! Да и не всегда есть возможность** оптимизировать все изображения, **т.е.** менять размеры или разрешение, а таких картинок на сайте много.

---

**Вопрос:** 
Почему срабатывает огромное разрешение для телефонов, а не уменьшенное при записи `<img src="images/img-1-1x.jpg" srcset="images/2x/img-1-2x.webp 2x" ...` ?

Как правильно использовать `srcset`, стоит ли вообще использовать данный атрибут?

**Какие есть возможности оптимизации изображений без потери качества, но с сохранением скорости для моб. девайсов (кроссбраузерный lazy load или любые другие способы, не знакомый мне fallback метод :) )?**

Comment: Вот тут как раз недавно все разжевали https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gHLPBlzGRT8

Comment: @AndreyFedorov, вроде webp дает только меньший размер, можно и просто `img srcset` использовать, но у меня он почему-то не так работает pagespeed ругается на 2x (большое) изображение, хотя по идее должно отображаться 1x.

Comment: Ну я не webp имел в виду, а тег `<picture>`, как комплексное решение.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov, спасибо! Полезный урок, нужно будет попробовать и webp формат добавить

Answer (score 2):

Делайте картинки в формате `webp` и добавляйте их в ваш `srcset`, этого гугл от вас и ждет, о чем вы бы и сами узнали, если бы развернули блок с ошибкой и прочитали что там написано.

Для изображений в форматах JPEG 2000, JPEG XR и WebP используется более эффективное сжатие, поэтому они загружаются быстрее и потребляют меньше трафика, чем изображения PNG и JPEG.

Вариант с `picture` наиболее кроссбраузерный.

```
<picture> 
  <source type="image/webp" srcset="images/img-1-1x.webp" /> 
  <img src="images/img-1-1x.jpg" /> 
</picture>
```

Сначала даете ему на съедение картинку в формате `webp` (как я вам в примере написал), если он не поддерживает такой тип, то будет грузить `jpg`.

Но гугл пейдж спид это расценит как ХОРОШО.

Comment: <picture>
    <source type="image/webp" srcset="images/img-1-1x.webp" />
    <img src="images/img-1-1x.jpg" />
 </picture>

Comment: Я знаю, что можно, только это не будет работать почти во всех браузерах. Не знаю как так вышло, что у всех есть, а у вас нет, но дословно там написано: Для изображений в форматах JPEG 2000, JPEG XR и WebP используется более эффективное сжатие, поэтому они загружаются быстрее и потребляют меньше трафика, чем изображения PNG и JPEG. Вариант с picture наиболее кроссбраузерный. Сначала даете ему на съедение картинку в формате webp (как я вам в примере написал), если он не поддерживает такой тип, то будет грузить jpg. Но гугл пейдж спид это расценит как ХОРОШО.

Comment: Мне больше не понятно почему для мобильной скорости ругается не на 1x, а на 2x ! А то что picture, поддержка я в курсе. Почему срабатывает огромное разрешение для телефонов, а не уменьшенное при записи `<img src="images/img-1-1x.jpg" srcset="images/2x/img-1-2x.webp 2x"` ))))

Answer (score 1):

Вообще можете тестировать и оптимизировать изображения в [gtmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/), но если поищите можете найти другие сайты для оптимизации, и еще в `photoshop` сохраните изображение с таким качеством что бы было оптимально `размер -> качество`.

И еще один важный момент. Это для мобильного сайта.

Изображения которые не должны быть видны в мобильном. сделайте фоном блока(если это возможно) в место тега `img`. И в определенный момент когда блок скрывается ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО для этого разрешения экрана поставьте для этого блока с фоновым изображением `background-image: none;`.

Вот таким образом в вы достаточно оптимизируете свою страницу.

Comment: gtmetrix мне нравится, но не устраивает заказчика) все ориентируются на page speed. "Изображения которые не должны быть видны в мобильном." Там видео есть, в вопросе ссылка на него есть. Да и проверено на практике, что хоть `img` хоть фон, хоть `display: none` хоть `display: block` все равно не оптимизируется страница (в видео подробно рассказывается)

Comment: @HamSter да я не говорю не использовать `pagespeed`. но вы для себя прогоните и в `gtmetrix`. он даст много полезной информации. и ктаму же может оптимизировать изображения. Я чуть позже скину сайт для хорошей оптимизации изображений.

Comment: под десктопы 90+ и gtmetrix пишет что все уже хорошо, а вот pagespeed именно для телефонов выдает низкую скорость

Comment: @HamSter а сколько низкое? и еще на что ругается? вы про фоновые картинки посмотрели что я писал?

Comment: в вопросе все описано и добавлена ссылка на видео в котором подробно и о фоновых картинках

Comment: @HamSter Да и еще вы должны обязательно сделать кеширование для картинок и прочего. посмотрите это. Посмотрите этот сайт. https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ifcmarkets.com%2F&tab=mobile, здесь все сделано так как я в ответе сказал.

Comment: Да, спасибо я поняла про фоновые картинки и кеширование настроено, но данный вариант меня точно не устраивает! Это не очень красиво и правильно все картинки в фон размещать, а для мобильных подменять, хотя и, как я вижу, практично. Спасибо за ответ и уделенное время!

Comment: @HamSter не за что, вообще то это правильно если картинку меняешь в мабильном или удаляешь блок. тогда это самый подхадящий вариант.

Comment: Если удаляешь, то проблем нет))

Answer (score 0):

А если в src ставить уменьшенную картинку, или заглушку и после загрузки скриптом менять из атрибута, причем можно и с проверкой разрешения окна и для мобильных брать например из data-mobile меньшего размера? Не знаю такой вариант обманет ли pageSpeed. Можно переписать на чистом JS

```js
$(function() {
  $('.big').html(function() {
      $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr('data'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class="big" src="blank.gif" data="https://google.com/favicon.ico"/>
<img class="big" src="blank.gif" data="https://yandex.com/favicon.ico"/>
```

Comment: Вообще то это обманет, но тогда весь сайт нужно будет менять на `js`, и еще с учетом `window resize`. А это уже совсем не удобно.

Comment: @RazGalstyan, что значит менять весь сайт на JS? Просто добавить атрибуты html тегам и добавить несколько строчек в один файл JS - что собственно в тексте вопроса и делается, но те результаты не устраивают (в частности плагин lazy load)

Comment: Ну да целый плагин для этого, а после гугл будет ругатся за большое количество `js`

Comment: @RazGalstyan мое решение без плагинов в 5 строчек кода, если на сайте не используется JQuery можно написать на JS и вставить или прямо в шаблон, или в уже имеющийся js файл.

Comment: Ну это да, а то с плагином я бы не сделал